# cmake error upon catkin make

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to the software, I was doing the following tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor/Tutorials/Quadrotor%20outdoor%20flight%20demo) and got a cmake error, I'm not sure how to " Add the installation prefix of "hardware_interface" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH" as it suggests, how can I fix it?

Full terminal text:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ mkdir ~/hector_quadrotor_tutorial
user@ubuntu:~$ cd ~/hector_quadrotor_tutorial
user@ubuntu:~/hector_quadrotor_tutorial$ wstool init src https://raw.github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/hydro-devel/tutorials.rosinstall
Using initial elements from: https://raw.github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/hydro-devel/tutorials.rosinstall
Writing /home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/.rosinstall
[hector_quadrotor] Fetching https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor.git (version hydro-devel) to /home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_quadrotor
Cloning into '/home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_quadrotor'...
remote: Counting objects: 2851, done.
remote: Total 2851 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 2851
Receiving objects: 100% (2851/2851), 726.82 KiB | 332.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1758/1758), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
[hector_quadrotor] Done.
[hector_slam] Fetching https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam.git (version catkin) to /home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_slam
Cloning into '/home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_slam'...
remote: Counting objects: 1827, done.
remote: Total 1827 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1827
Receiving objects: 100% (1827/1827), 338.44 KiB | 236.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1112/1112), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
[hector_slam] Done.
[hector_localization] Fetching https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_localization.git (version catkin) to /home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_localization
Cloning into '/home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_localization'...
remote: Counting objects: 2620, done.
remote: Total 2620 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 2620
Receiving objects: 100% (2620/2620), 3.69 MiB | 1.22 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1948/1948), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
[hector_localization] Done.
[hector_gazebo] Fetching https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_gazebo.git (version hydro-devel) to /home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo
Cloning into '/home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_gazebo'...
remote: Counting objects: 1499, done.
remote: Total 1499 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1499
Receiving objects: 100% (1499/1499), 2.08 MiB | 789.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (950/950), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
[hector_gazebo] Done.
[hector_models] Fetching https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_models.git (version hydro-devel) to /home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_models
Cloning into '/home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_models'...
remote: Counting objects: 630, done.
remote: Total 630 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 630
Receiving objects: 100% (630/630), 207.65 KiB | 199.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (414/414), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
[hector_models] Done.

update complete.
user@ubuntu:~/hector_quadrotor_tutorial$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial
Source space: /home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src
Build space: /home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/build
Devel space: /home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/devel
Install space: /home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/install
Creating symlink "/home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/CMakeLists.txt" pointing to "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake"
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/user/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /home/user/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.6") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/build/test_results
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.14
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 37 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - hector_components_description
-- ~~  - hector_gazebo (metapackage)
-- ~~  - hector_gazebo_worlds
-- ~~  - hector_localization (metapackage)
-- ~~  - hector_models (metapackage)
-- ~~  - hector_quadrotor
-- ~~  - hector_quadrotor_demo
-- ~~  - hector_quadrotor_description
-- ~~  - hector_sensors_description
-- ~~  - hector_sensors_gazebo
-- ~~  - hector_slam (metapackage)
-- ~~  - hector_slam_launch
-- ~~  - hector_xacro_tools
-- ~~  - hector_uav_msgs
-- ~~  - hector_map_tools
-- ~~  - hector_nav_msgs
-- ~~  - hector_geotiff
-- ~~  - hector_geotiff_plugins
-- ~~  - hector_marker_drawing
-- ~~  - hector_quadrotor_controller
-- ~~  - hector_quadrotor_controller_gazebo
-- ~~  - hector_quadrotor_model
-- ~~  - hector_quadrotor_teleop
-- ~~  - hector_compressed_map_transport
-- ~~  - hector_gazebo_plugins
-- ~~  - hector_imu_attitude_to_tf
-- ~~  - hector_imu_tools
-- ~~  - hector_map_server
-- ~~  - hector_pose_estimation_core
-- ~~  - hector_pose_estimation
-- ~~  - hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins
-- ~~  - hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation
-- ~~  - hector_trajectory_server
-- ~~  - message_to_tf
-- ~~  - hector_mapping
-- ~~  - hector_gazebo_thermal_camera
-- ~~  - hector_quadrotor_gazebo
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_components_description'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_models/hector_components_description)
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'hector_gazebo'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_gazebo_worlds'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_worlds)
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'hector_localization'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_localization/hector_localization)
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'hector_models'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_models/hector_models)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_quadrotor'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_quadrotor_demo'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_demo)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_quadrotor_description'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_description)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_sensors_description'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_models/hector_sensors_description)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_sensors_gazebo'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_gazebo/hector_sensors_gazebo)
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'hector_slam'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_slam)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_slam_launch'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_slam_launch)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_xacro_tools'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_models/hector_xacro_tools)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_uav_msgs'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_quadrotor/hector_uav_msgs)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- hector_uav_msgs: 21 messages, 0 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_map_tools'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_map_tools)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_nav_msgs'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_nav_msgs)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- hector_nav_msgs: 0 messages, 5 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_geotiff'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_geotiff)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found
-- Found Qt4: /usr/bin/qmake (found suitable version "4.8.6", minimum required is "4.6") 
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.26") 
-- checking for module 'eigen3'
--   found eigen3, version 3.2.0
-- Found Eigen: /usr/include/eigen3  
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_geotiff_plugins'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_geotiff_plugins)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_marker_drawing'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_marker_drawing)
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_quadrotor_controller'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_controller)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "hardware_interface" with any of the following names:

    hardware_interfaceConfig.cmake
    hardware_interface-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "hardware_interface" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "hardware_interface_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "hardware_interface" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_controller/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/user/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
user@ubuntu:~/hector_quadrotor_tutorial$ ^C
user@ubuntu:~/hector_quadrotor_tutorial$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210633/cmake-error-upon-catkin-make/) by [c123](https://answers.ros.org/users/22663/c123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-06-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-05**:
The tutorial you linked has two options: *Install binary packages* and *Install from source*. Any particular reason you cannot install the binary pkgs? That would remove the need to build everything locally with `catkin_make`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-05**:
Btw, the solution to your issue is to make sure you have all dependencies of the `hector_quadrotor_controller` pkg installed (using `rosdep install ..` fi). But if you install the binary versions, that would all be a non-issue, as all dependencies are already taken care of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just used the binary versions, thanks for the help.

---

Originally posted by [c123](https://answers.ros.org/users/22663/c123/) with karma: 1 on 2015-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0